# Check distinct values of list, count them and return top 3

Tags: excel, count, distinct, countif

I'm looking for a formula to check in a list of values on EXCEL, first check which values are unique, then getting those values count how many of them exist. Finally I want to appear the top 3 of the values.

Example:

## List   --------- Distinct ------- COUNT ----- TOP 3

3        -------------------- 1 -------------------------- 1 --------------------- 3

4  -------------------- 2 -------------------------- 3 --------------------- 2

5 -------------------- 3 -------------------------- 4 ---------------------- 5

9 -------------------- 4 -------------------------- 1

3 -------------------- 5 -------------------------- 2

1 -------------------- 9 -------------------------- 1

2

2

3

5

3

2

I want to find after a column that gets me everything in one.
I know how to count them, how to sort them, but when adding the sort and only getting me the top 3 is confusing me. Can't find a good formula all together to return what I want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: mark the list and click on the `Data` tab in the `Get & Transfrom Data` section on the button `From Table/ Range`.

<sub>(a new window with the query editor will open up showing your list)</sub>
[image]

Step2: click on `Group By` on the `Home` tab within the `Transform` section (in the newly opened `Query Editor` window).

Step3: leave the defalts as group by `basic` and group by `IDs` (in my example or whichever column name you have). Then give the new column a name and select `Count Rows` and confirm with `OK`.

[image]

Step4: on the new `count` column (or whichever name you chose) click the down arrow and select `sort descending`.

Step5: `Right-click` on the table icon to keep only the top 3 rows...

[image]

Step6: click `Close & Load`.

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Really well explained and helped a lot, thought that a formula was better, is there any possibility for a formula? What if I add more values to the table, always getting new values from 30 to 30 mins?

Comment: No formula can achieve this as a  `distinct` list will vary in size. Hence, your list will have to dynamically adjust to the amount of items there are in your list. So, somethimes you'd need formulas in 5 rows, sometimes maybe in 12 rows or maybe there are even 87 distinct values and hence you'd need 87 rows with formulas. So, either you use the above solution or you make use of VBA programming (in which case you'd have to program that as nowone here will do that for you). BTW, the above solution automatically adjusts based on the underlying table: right-click the result and select `refresh`.

Comment: Yes i'm understanding. Thanks a lot for the explanation! Your solution already solves a lot of problems for me!